# HP printer changes serial itself

Tags: usb, printer, cups, hplip

I have HP LaserJet Professional P1102 using CUPS via USB.
Sometimes it has serial=000000000Q81E02RSI1c, sometimes serial=000000000Q81E02RPR1a. But this is same printer, with same formater.

Hplip version is 3.11.10

Any workarounds to not reinstalling queue in cups every month?

Comment: Please read ***[ask]***, then edit your question to be more clear. At this point, you are not even asking a question and this is likely to be closed.

Comment: What serial number is that and where do you see it?  Why is it important?  How are you identifying/specifying the printer in CUPS?  What actual problems are you experiencing?

Comment: Then printer changes serial spooler cant send pages to it. Needed to delete and reinstall or modify printer, after send pages one more time.

Comment: @eri: fyi, if you "address" comments like I did this one, the user will receive an alert.  Otherwise, nobody will be aware of your comment posting unless they stumble across it.  It isn't clear why you need to deal with such internal numbers at all.  CUPS is much more user-friendly than that.  If you let CUPS find your printer through the built-in wizard, it will set things up the proper way.

Comment: @fixer1234 with cups wizard serial also included

Comment: How are the printer and its connection identified in CUPS?  Where are you seeing the serial number?  There are many ways to specify the printer in CUPS.  It may just be a question of specifying it differently.